# Moodle 2.9: When I upload a csv with new users, the password is not generated

Tags: moodle

i'm learning to use moodle and I have on issue with the Upload Users functionality.

I load the CSV and the users are created without problems. In the CSV I don't specify any password so i mark the "Generate password" option.

I suppose that an email notification has to be sent to the new users with their generated password, but it is not sending nothing.

I've checked the users table and the password value is "to be generated", so it seems that the function that generate the passwords and send the email is not being called.

I tried creating a user in the "Add user" section, and when I create it marking the "Generate password" option, the password is generated and the email is sent.

Does I have to mark any option that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've founded what i was missing. When you upload users with a csv, the passwords are generated in the moodle cron, and I forgot to put the cron in the server crontab.

Now it works fine.

Comment: That's great for you. I have a related issue; I made the same steps you described in the question. My system does send e-mails, but they only contain the text defined in the section Plugins/Local Plugins/Moodle welcome. There is no password field; users only get their username. Which e-mail template does your system use? That one from Moodle welcome section or some other one? How do you refer to password in this text?